# How to resize mysql> innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:5G;? Using Mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql

I tried to resize in many different ways but I always get the same error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'innodb_temp_data_file_path=ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:500M' at line 1

Comment: that's not a MySQL command, but config variable, you should edit your configuration file to contain that directive, not to run it on MySQL-Cli.

Answer (score 0):

As mysql manual on [sysvar_innodb_temp_data_file_path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_temp_data_file_path) says, it is not a dynamic variable, therefore cannot be set using `set sysvar_innodb_temp_data_file_path=...` method via sql. You need to include it either in your mysql config file or as a startup parameter to the mysql service.